# How do I refresh discord oauth2 token in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, python-requests, discord.py

The problem is that the code expires after a certain amount of time how would I make it so it doesn't expire. I need to keep the codes for different users in a database and want to make sure they don't expire. This is the discord docs for this topic but it is not working for me: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant-refresh-token-exchange-example

So far this is my code:

```py
API_ENDPOINT = 'https://discord.com/api/v8'
CLIENT_ID = ''
CLIENT_SECRET = ''
REDIRECT_URI = "https://google.com"

def exchange_code(code):
  data = {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': code,
    'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI
  }
  headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
  r = requests.post('%s/oauth2/token' % API_ENDPOINT, data=data, headers=headers)
  r.raise_for_status()
  return r.json()

r = exchange_code("#The code I get from oauth2")
code = r["access_token"]
```

Comment: any errors came?

Comment: So far, you have only implemented the OAuth2 authorization code flow. This will issue you an access and a refresh token. Once the access token expires (I believe it lasts for a week), you can use the refresh token to obtain a new one. You already linked to the correct part of the docs, take a look at the `refresh_token` function example showcased there

Comment: ok will take a look